# Publishing Lightswitch localy

Tags: publish, visual-studio-lightswitch, iis-8.5

I'm trying to publish ligthswitch on local network with from VisualStudio 2013,

I have installed IIS and launched web-deployment services. I Think I also installed all the possible features from web platform installer.
When I publish lightswitch app I get to this screen.
and I dont know how to get pass this service Url line. Whenever I type localhost or Computer name which is the server name, perhaps? I get an error 
"Lightswitch must be run with administrative privileges to deploy to local host.
[image]

I fugured I could also just use import settings file. It could be alternative way.[image]

but how do I create this xml file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've answered this for you before.  You may have missed a step:

1. Open IIS
2. Locate "Default Web Site"
3. Right click and find Deploy -> Configure Web Deploy Publishing... (This step will create the XML file that you can use for Import Settings...

(If this menu option isn't available it means you haven't got the Management Service installed.  And/or you haven't got the ALL of the Web Deploy 3.5 components installed.)